# What goes into the "other" section of java's native memory tracking output?

Tags: java, performance, memory, jvm, java-11

I'm trying to debug a Java application with high memory usage. Using native memory tracking I found that there's a lot of memory being used by a section called "Other". I can't seem to find any information online about what might be stored here, what might cause it to be high, or how to debug it further. Any help along these lines would be greatly appreciated. For reference here's the output I get from jcmd:

```
Total: reserved=49GB, committed=48GB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=32GB, committed=32GB)
                            (mmap: reserved=32GB, committed=32GB)

-                    Thread (reserved=1GB, committed=0GB)
                            (thread #1291)
                            (stack: reserved=1GB, committed=0GB)

-                        GC (reserved=2GB, committed=2GB)
                            (mmap: reserved=1GB, committed=1GB)

-                     Other (reserved=14GB, committed=14GB)
                            (malloc=14GB #1520)
```

Comment: maybe some direct ByteBuffer?

Comment: @cello not maybe - but exactly right.

Comment: in our load tests with graphql of "sum by(pod) (jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes{id="direct"})" it is closer to Other, not Internal. java 11.0.8.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Other` section of NMT report counts off-heap memory allocated by an application either through [Direct ByteBuffers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) or immediately via `Unsafe.allocateMemory`. `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect` calls `Unsafe.allocateMemory` under the hood.

You can monitor the number of Direct ByteBuffers and the total memory occupied by them via JMX - look for BufferPool MBean:

[image: BufferPool MBean]

[Async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/) can help to find where off-heap memory is allocated. Run

```
profiler.sh -d <duration> -e jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory -f profile.html <pid>
```

This will create a flame graph, showing stack traces of all places where `Unsafe.allocateMemory` (including `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect`) is called from:

[image: Unsafe.allocateMemory]

For more information about ByteBuffers and their relation to off-heap memory usage, see [this presentation](https://youtu.be/c755fFv1Rnk?t=1615).

Comment: what is the equivalent intellij parameters to perform the following operation: profiler.sh -d <duration> -e jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory -f profile.html <pid>

Answer (score 1):

You should have said you use `java-11` (or higher), because previously this was called `Internal` (and it included a bit more).

This is every allocation via `ByteBuffer::allocateDirect`.

Comment: NMT does not track memory consumed by Mapped ByteBuffers (i.e. FileChannel.map).

Comment: @apangin oh, really? I honestly thought it does. Thank you